# How to edit the /etc/profile?

Tags: linux, bash

My profile only load the last line command after I run `source /etc/profile`. Besides after this command, The OS normal command like ls vim are all not found. It's so wired and I konw I can change the `~./bashrc`, however why this change are fail? How can I load all the "export"?

Here is my changed `/etc/profile`. I add the `PATH` at the end of the original file.

```sh
    pathmunge () {
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$1":*)
                ;;
            *)
                if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                    PATH=$PATH:$1
                else
                    PATH=$1:$PATH
                fi
        esac
    }


    if [ -x /usr/bin/id ]; then
        if [ -z "$EUID" ]; then
            # ksh workaround
            EUID=`/usr/bin/id -u`
            UID=`/usr/bin/id -ru`
        fi
        USER="`/usr/bin/id -un`"
        LOGNAME=$USER
        MAIL="/var/spool/mail/$USER"
    fi

    # Path manipulation
    if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
        pathmunge /usr/sbin
        pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
    else
        pathmunge /usr/local/sbin after
        pathmunge /usr/sbin after
    fi

    HOSTNAME=`/usr/bin/hostname 2>/dev/null`
    HISTSIZE=1000
    if [ "$HISTCONTROL" = "ignorespace" ] ; then
        export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
    else
        export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
    fi

    export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL

    # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for login shell
    # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
    # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
    # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
        umask 002
    fi

    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    done

    unset i
    unset -f pathmunge

    export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

    #JAVA
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_241
    export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/dt.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
    export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

    #nginx
    export PATH=/usr/local/nginx/sbin

    #maven
    M2_HOME=/opt/maven-3.6.3
    export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: I am so tupid. The path should be divided by ":", so every Path should be add and divided by ":"

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

#JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_241
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/dt.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

#nginx
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nginx/sbin

#maven
M2_HOME=/opt/maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:${M2_HOME}/bin
```